# Debugging a For-loop; Fast-Forward

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

So I'm working on a project where I have really long for loops and I'm usually encountering problems when getting close to the end of the loop, but it's pretty much impossible to get there manually by stepping into the loop millions of time. I know I could just change the counter variable, but in this case it would not work because the side-effects of each iteration wont happen. Is there a way to make a breakpoint stop on a place after 999999998 iterations?
I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2010

Answer (score 19, accepted):

put a breakpoint, 
right click on it, 
choose condition 
set

```
i == 999999998 //if your loop looks like for (var i == 0;....
```

Comment: I did this, which is probably what I'm looking for, but now when there is a breakpoint, he debugging pauses every thousand or so iterations and to continue I have to click on the "Break All" option on the IntelliTrace Window. Any idea why is this stopping and how to cancel this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

I am just pasting an image to visualize Raphaël Althaus's Answer
 [image]

Answer (score 3):

As Raphaël says, you can set a condition on a breakpoint. However, if this happens in a tight loop the overhead of the condition can be quite significant. I've found that doing the check in the code and calling [Debugger.Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) works much better in that case.